# Django Crispy Form loop through {% crispy %} object

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to use crispy form fields within each table's column. I can render it using:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<tr>
    <form method="get" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
        {% for field in filter.form %}
            <th>{{ field|as_crispy_field }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        <input class='hidden-submit' type="submit"/>
    </form>
</tr>
```

And it looks like this which is what I want:

[image]

But the problem is my `Layout()` which I'm using to add extra parameters such has placeholders etc to the form is not working because I'm using `|as_crispy_field` tag to render individual fields. Here is my form component:

```
class CustomFiltersForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(

        )

        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            self.helper.layout.append(Field(field_name, placeholder="Search " + field.label))
```

Is there a way to loop through `{% crispy filter.form %}` or an alternative way to populate individual fields using crispy forms? Something like:

```
{% for field in {% crispy filter.form%} %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You could do something like the following and put the "th" tag in the layout
from crispy_forms.layout import HTML
for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
    self.helper.layout.append(HTML("<th>"))
    self.helper.layout.append(Field(field_name, placeholder="Search " + field.label))
    self.helper.layout.append(HTML("</th>"))

Comment: I did try that but that produces the form inside <th> tag and form fields outside of the table. I should have mentioned that I'm using django-tables2 to populate the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do two different things, either you render the fields manually or you render them through the layout option on the crispy form helper. I would ditch the individual field approach and just go with the layout option that way the placeholders and multiple attributes you add will be visible.

Forms should look something like this.

class CustomFiltersForm(forms.Form):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_show_labels = False
    self.helper.form_tag = False

    for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
        self.helper.layout.append(Column(Field(field_name, placeholder="Search " + field.label)))
        self.helper.layout.append(Hidden(Submit("submit"))
```

Template should look something like this:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<tr>
    <form method="get" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
        {% crispy filter_form %}
    </form>
</tr>
```

Comment: This does not work for me as I'm using django-tables2 to populate the table and this produces the form outside of the table columns.